# Rails defining database for globalize translations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, globalize

I use globalize for translations in my Rails 4 App. I use two databases for my project. One for central data and one for local data. Now i want to establish a connection for my models translations. But I don't know how to doing this. I use an abstract class to establish the connections for my models, but how do i do this for the translation_tables?
Problem:

- Database of model: central (correct)
- Database of translation: local
  (wrong)

My Abstract class:

```
class CentralBase < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection DB_CENTRAL
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

My model with translation

```
class Additive < CentralBase
  translates :name
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay seems to be something like this:

```
class Additive < CentralBase
  translates :name
  translation_class.establish_connection DB_Central
  ...
end
```

But a solution which put this line in the abstract class or something would be nice.